# nativecode=1260 ** Row 60 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: civireport, mysql

After an upgrade from 5.7.x to 5.13.x, a standard contribution/detail report started failing. In the CiviCRM admin log, we see this sql error:

```
nativecode=1260 ** Row 60 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()
```

Which appears to be getting generated at line 546 of civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Detail.php
i.e. creating a temporary table as part of the post processing.

This is a monthly report for credit card contributions, a similar one for ACH/EFT is not failing, so it appears to be some kind of limit issue.

One solution appears to be to update a mysql setting, as noted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208773/mysql-row-30153-was-cut-by-group-concat-error

On this server (mariadb 10.1), the setting is not specifically configured, and has the default setting:
group_concat_max_len = 1024

Answer (score 1):

As an ad-hoc solution, I put

```
CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=15000');
```

In the report code, before line 546, and that fixed it.